# PHP - Counting elements in MySQL query returns double the number of elements

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the number of columns on a SQL query result. Whenever I try to use `count($row)` the table should have only 4 elements but it shows 8, and the `implode(",",$row)` show that in fact there are 8 elements but the output of that is a bit odd:

Code fragment:

```
$query = $con->query($sql);

$rows = array();

error_log($sql);
if(!$query){error_log(mysqli_error($con));exit;}
while($row = $query->fetch_array()){
    $rows[]=$row;
}

if(count($rows)==0) { echo "101";   exit; }

echo '{"row":[';
foreach($rows as $key=>$row) {
    error_log(count($row));
    error_log(implode(",",$row));
    error_log($row[0]." ".$row[1]." ".$row[2]." ".$row[3]);
}
echo "]}";
```

Result:

```
[Tue May 29 13:47:21 2018] 8
[Tue May 29 13:47:21 2018] AFI,AFI,001,001,Pancho,Pancho,a1d7584daaca4738d499ad7082886b01117275d8,a1d7584daaca4738d499ad7082886b01117275d8
[Tue May 29 13:47:21 2018] AFI 001 Pancho a1d7584daaca4738d499ad7082886b01117275d8
```

As you can see, the eight elements are there but they are just duplicates of the correct output, represented by `error_log($row[0]." ".$row[1]." ".$row[2]." ".$row[3]);`.

Does anyone know why PHP does it like this? Is there a way to get the correct number of elements on the query row?

Comment: Use `fetch_assoc()` or use `MYSQLI_ASSOC` with `fetch_array()`

Comment: Also, consider using `json_encode()` instead of building JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour of [`fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-resul) is to both have indexes with column-names as with numerical positions. When you do a `var_dump` of your $row, you would see something similar to:

```
array(
    0 => 'AFI',
    'column_name_1' => 'AFI',
    1 => '001',
    'column_name_2' => '001',
    // and so on
)
```

`fetch_array()` takes one single argument to change this behaviour. The default is `MYSQLI_BOTH` giving above output. You can change this to `$query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)` to get only the numerical indexes or `$query->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)` to get only the values with column-names on the index.

When using either one of those, the `count()` will also give the correct number of columns.

Note: `$query->fetch_row()` is the same (and shorter) as `$query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)` and `$query->fetch_assoc()` the same as `$query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)`. Instead of using `fetch_array()` with the array-notation-argument you might prefer one of those functions instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this was really helpful. I ended just doing a `json encode`, but `fetch_row` is very useful for this and other problems I'm having with the same server.

Answer (score 1):

that behaviour is just fine, because the array holds both index numbers and column names, so that you can access a field conveniently either by `$row[0]` or `$row['col_name']`

try to use a rowCount method instead. Here is the code in case you use mysqli:

```
echo $query->num_rows();
```

Answer (score 1):

you are getting result in array format which has both numbered and associative array.

```
$query->fetch_array() or $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH) // this fetches both type
```

while this

```
$query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) // this fetches as associative array
```

and for only numbered array

```
$query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM); // this as numbered array
```